# I need help for this php to js connection in which I use at first a sql query that gets my data and then I encode that fetched data into JSON format

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysql, json

I have a problem with a project that I'm doing alone for a sidecart in a php file with links to sql,css and js that are all external , the problem started when I tried to add data needed in js with the encoding into JSON data

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lost in Time</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="realsitefixed.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lostintime');
$q1 = "Select * From risorse where IDRISORSE=1";
$risLogo = mysqli_query($conn, $q1);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($risLogo)) {
    ?>

    <a class="logo-centrato">
        <img class="logo" src="<?php echo $data['NOMEFILE']; ?>">
    </a>

<?php } ?>

<!-- Navigation bar -->
<div class="barraMenu">
    <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'Site.php'"><i class="icon fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'loginlit.php'"><i class="icon fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>

    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) echo "<a><i class='fa-solid fa-person'></i>&nbsp; Benvenuto: &nbsp;$_SESSION[name]&nbsp; $_SESSION[surname] </a>"; ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="<?php session_destroy(); ?> window.location.href = 'realSite.php'"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a>
    <a class="# cart"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i><span class="numb"> 0</span></a>
</div>

<form method='POST'>
    <?php
    $qHoodie = "Select * From risorse where IDRISORSE=3";
    $risHoodie = mysqli_query($conn, $qHoodie);
    while ($dataHoodie = mysqli_fetch_assoc($risHoodie)) {
        ?>
        

        <div class='sidecart'>
            <div class='cartTab'>
                <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
            </div>

            <div class='items'>
                
            </div>
            <div class='actions'>
                <div class='buttons'>
                    <button class='close'>Close</button>
                    <button class='checkOut'>Check Out</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product_container">
            <div class="item1">
                <img class="item" href="hoodiegustavedorexlostinime.php"
                     src="<?php echo $dataHoodie['NOMEFILE']; ?>" alt="imgprod1">
                <br>
                <div class="price"> &euro;49.99</div>
                <br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <?php
                $qTaglie = "Select DISTINCT TAGLIA From capo; ";
                $risTaglie = mysqli_query($conn, $qTaglie);
                $qNtaglie = "Select count(DISTINCT Taglia) as nTaglie from capo;";
                $risNTaglie = mysqli_query($conn, $qNtaglie);

                while ($dataNTaglie = mysqli_fetch_assoc($risNTaglie)) {
                    ?>
                    <select name="taglie" class="taglie">
                        <?php
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $dataNTaglie['nTaglie']; $i++) {
                            while ($dataTaglie = mysqli_fetch_assoc($risTaglie)) {
                                echo "<option value='" . $dataTaglie['TAGLIA'] . "'>" . $dataTaglie['TAGLIA'] . "</option>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>

                <?php
                    $qQuantita = "Select distinct QUANTITA From capo C join possiede P on C.IDCAPO=P.IDCAPO";
                    $risQuantita = mysqli_query($conn, $qQuantita);
                    while ($dataQuantita = mysqli_fetch_assoc($risQuantita)) {
                ?>
                <select name="quantita" class="quantita">
                    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $dataQuantita['QUANTITA']; $i++) {
                        echo"<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                
                <input type="submit" class="itemButton" name="add" value="Add to Cart" >
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
                        $_SESSION['qta'] = $_POST['quantita'];
                        $_SESSION['selectedTaglia'] = $_POST['taglie'];
                        $_SESSION['selectedImage'] = $dataHoodie['IDRISORSE']; 
                        $qNomeCapo = "SELECT IDCAPO, NOME, PREZZO, NOMEFILE FROM capo c join risorse r on c.IMG = r.IDRISORSE 
                        WHERE TAGLIA = '" . $_SESSION['selectedTaglia'] . "' AND IMG ='" . $_SESSION['selectedImage'] . "'";
                        $resultNomeCapo = mysqli_query($conn, $qNomeCapo);
                        if($resultNomeCapo && mysqli_num_rows($resultNomeCapo) > 0) {
                            $rowNomeCapo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultNomeCapo);
                            $_SESSION['idCapo'] =  $rowNomeCapo['IDCAPO'];
                            $_SESSION['nomeCapo'] = $rowNomeCapo['NOME'];
                            $_SESSION['prezzoCapo'] = $rowNomeCapo['PREZZO'];
                            $_SESSION['nomeFile'] = $rowNomeCapo['NOMEFILE'];
                            // Encode fetched data into JSON format
                            $itemData = array(
                                'id' => $_SESSION['idCapo'],
                                'nome' => $_SESSION['nomeCapo'],
                                'prezzo' => $_SESSION['prezzoCapo'],
                                'quantita' => $_SESSION['qta'],
                                'nomefile' => $_SESSION['nomeFile']
                            );
                            json_encode($itemData);
                            //json_encode($itemData);
                           
                        } else {
                            echo "Error: No data found.";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
</form>

<script src="cartphp.js"></script>
</body>
```

i know that some of this values can be defined without a session but i just tried everything so the code has stayed like that from the last save

this is the js :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const cartButton = document.querySelector('.cart');
    const closeButton = document.querySelector('.close');
    const cartContainer = document.querySelector('.sidecart');
    const itemsContainer = document.querySelector('.items');
    const checkOutButton = document.querySelector('.checkOut');
    const numbSpan = document.querySelector('.numb');
    const cart = [];

    if (!cartButton || !closeButton || !cartContainer || !itemsContainer || !checkOutButton || !numbSpan) {
        console.error('One or more required elements not found.');
        return;
    }

    
    cartButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        cartContainer.classList.toggle('show');
    });

    
    closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        cartContainer.classList.remove('show');
    });

    
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        fetch('realSite.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new FormData(this)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            
            addToCart(data);
            
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    });

  
    function addToCart(itemData) {
        

        const itemElement = document.createElement('div');
        itemElement.classList.add('item');
        itemElement.innerHTML = `
            <div class="imageitem">
                <img src="${itemData.nomefile}" >
            </div>
            <div class="nameitem">${itemData.nome}</div>
            <div class="totalPrice">€${itemData.prezzo * itemData.quantita}</div>
            <div class="quantity">
                <span class="minus"><</span>
                <span>${itemData.quantita}</span>
                <span class="plus">></span>
            </div>
        `;
        console.log(itemElement);

        itemsContainer.appendChild(itemElement);
        cartContainer.classList.toggle('show');

        numbSpan.innerText = calculateTotalQuantity();
    }

    function calculateTotalQuantity() {
        let totalQuantity = 0;
        cart.forEach(itemData => {
            totalQuantity += itemData.quantity;
        });
        return totalQuantity;
    }
});
```

and the error that the console gives me as it doesn't pick this data as fetched but it takes it as an html

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<head> "... is not valid JSON
```

I think i understand that the data is not well fetched in that JSON format

but I'm litterally a newbie with this languages (JS,JSON) so if you can provide me an explanation and if possible a solution , It'll help me a lot

If there is something else that you need of the js php sql or css  I'll provide it

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing here that shows what realSite.php is doing, which is the problematic file as it's returning HTML.

Comment: I' ve posted the whole php

Comment: The file you're calling is outputting HTML. Where's the one to get the data and output JSON? The problem is ` fetch('realSite.php')` is fetching an HTML page, not a JSON result from some resource.

Comment: and how can I fetch data from a html page like this into a JSON result ?? Is it impossible ??

Comment: To get the results as JSON you call PHP that specifically returns JSON. It's not that file because that file is outputting some buttons.

Comment: `json_encode($itemData);` by itself doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok wow I didn't the `if isset post` that's in there randomly.

Comment: @gre_gor and how can it be done??

Answer (score -1):

The JSON result that is expected would look something like this:

```json
{
  "id": 23,
  "nome": "Foo Bar",
  "prezzo": 42.42,
  "quantita": 1,
  "nomefile": "foo.zip"
}
```

So the response must not start with `<head>…`, which is HTML (not exactly a completely valid document b/c it is not wrapped in `<html>…</html>`, but that's another story) that already contains characters invalid for JSON as defined in [RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627).

Restructuring your code, moving the whole `if(isset($_POST['add'])){…}` content up in the file would make it work, something like:

```php
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $_SESSION['qta'] = $_POST['quantita'];
    $_SESSION['selectedTaglia'] = $_POST['taglie'];
    $_SESSION['selectedImage'] = $dataHoodie['IDRISORSE']; 
    $qNomeCapo = "SELECT IDCAPO, NOME, PREZZO, NOMEFILE FROM capo c join risorse r on c.IMG = r.IDRISORSE 
    WHERE TAGLIA = '" . $_SESSION['selectedTaglia'] . "' AND IMG ='" . $_SESSION['selectedImage'] . "'";
    $resultNomeCapo = mysqli_query($conn, $qNomeCapo);
    if($resultNomeCapo && mysqli_num_rows($resultNomeCapo) > 0) {
        $rowNomeCapo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultNomeCapo);
        $_SESSION['idCapo'] =  $rowNomeCapo['IDCAPO'];
        $_SESSION['nomeCapo'] = $rowNomeCapo['NOME'];
        $_SESSION['prezzoCapo'] = $rowNomeCapo['PREZZO'];
        $_SESSION['nomeFile'] = $rowNomeCapo['NOMEFILE'];
        // Encode fetched data into JSON format
        $itemData = array(
            'id' => $_SESSION['idCapo'],
            'nome' => $_SESSION['nomeCapo'],
            'prezzo' => $_SESSION['prezzoCapo'],
            'quantita' => $_SESSION['qta'],
            'nomefile' => $_SESSION['nomeFile']
        );

        echo json_encode($itemData);       
    } else {
        echo json_encode([
            "error" => "Not found", 
            "debug" => "foo bar "
        ]);       
    }
    
    die();
}
?>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lost in Time</title>
    <!-- The rest of the page follows …
```

That should do the job, providing your database retrieval code works as expected.

Note the added `header()` command and the added `echo` in front of `json_encode` – without the latter your code would not output anything (as `json_encode` only does the transformation from array to JSON string, but you also want to output it) and the former sets the correct HTTP header as kindly pointed out by [popnoodles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822711/popnoodles). Also they make the valid argument that you'd need all responses to be JSON, b/c that way you can implement more structured error handling, have consistent responses, and most importantly your JS code will simply break at `response.json()` when no matching result is found in the database.

You'll need to handle this case in your JS, so add a check for `data.error !== undefined` and handle it instead of calling `addToCart()`.

---

My two cents: I cannot help but notice that this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, e.g. an attacker can easily delete your complete database. Rewriting your query using [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) can mitigate that. Just one example of numerous things that can go seriously wrong when developing a website this way.

If this is a small project that is just for fun, a sandbox or simple exercise, go ahead and have fun learning. But if you are looking to build a real-world shopping website that's scalable, trustworthy and also works, i feel obliged to advise for a different approach. The current code contains state management, database CRUD, static presentation, routing, user interactivity, etc. in one, maybe several big files w/o clear structural separation. This "advantage" – that PHP makes this so easy – made it successful in the early days and is still appealing as it's a great DX for newbies, but at the same time it is probably its biggest downfall and the reason PHP is so notoriously hated in the dev landscape.

Nevertheless, you can stand on the shoulders of giants using the right framework for the job, helping you to avoid costly (and painful) mistakes others have made (and paid for) numerous times before you.

It's hard to make an ultimate recommendation w/o knowing your exact requirements, but it's never a bad idea to learn one, nowadays Laravel would be the noteworthy big one, while i personally enjoyed [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) and [Yii](https://www.yiiframework.com/) a lot, all of which can enable you to build bigger sites while providing you with a lot of structure and best practices. Of course, if you want to fire up a commercial site to sell stuff, there are lots of specialized PHP solution such as WooCommerce or Magento.

Comment: Great that you found their hidden $_POST request bit, but `echo "Error: No data found.";` is not outputting valid JSON. Why would you cause it to break just because there's no matching data? Also `json_encode($itemData);` outputs nothing. And where are the JSON headers? Happy to un-downvote once this is fixed.

Comment: @Popnoodles Fair points raised. I wasn't sure where to end and where to start, so i just wanted to give them a hint to overcome the immediate structural problem they seemed to be bumping against here along with some general outlook. Thought of the headers, but i believe most JS clients would still be able to process the JSON (however it won't hurt and is of course the correct way to do it – while putting one more topic onto the table).  I honestly overlooked the missing echo, so thanks.